# Sorting numbers in shuffle.js so the order is correct i.e. 1, 3, 5, 10 etc

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I think I lack a bit of knowledge in Javascript and have been stumped on this one for a long time.

If anyone is familiar with [shuffle.js](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) you might be able to help. I'm basically just trying to sort a list of products by price but javascript's sort function doesn't do prices correctly. I know the function I need to make it sort prices but the issue I have is the shuffle.js code doesn't seem to create an array of numbers. I'm actually really confused how it works. What I have so far is:

```
var Shuffle = window.shuffle;


var Products = function (element) {
    this.element = element;

    this.addShuffleEventListeners();

    this.shuffle = new Shuffle(element, {
        itemSelector: '.product',
        sizer: null,
        speed: 350
    });

    this.addSorting();
    this.mode = 'exclusive';
};

Products.prototype.toArray = function (arrayLike) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike);
};

Products.prototype.addSorting = function () {
    var menu = document.querySelector('.sort-options');

    if (!menu) {
        return;
    }

    menu.addEventListener('change', this._handleSortChange.bind(this));
};

Products.prototype._handleSortChange = function (evt) {
    var value = evt.target.value;
    var options = {};

    function sortByPrice(element) {
        return element.getAttribute('data-price');
    }

    if (value === 'price_desc') {
        options = {
            by: sortByPrice,
        };
    }
    else if (value === 'price_asc') {
        options = {
            reverse: true,
            by: sortByPrice,
        };
    }

    this.shuffle.sort(options);
};

Products.prototype.addShuffleEventListeners = function () {
    var handler = function (event) {
        console.log('type: %s', event.type, 'detail:', event.detail);
    };

    this.element.addEventListener(Shuffle.EventType.LAYOUT, handler, false);
    this.element.addEventListener(Shuffle.EventType.REMOVED, handler, false);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    window.product = new Products(document.getElementById('grid'));
});
```

If I do a

```
console.log(options)
```

I  can't find an array of the numbers anywhere so I can compare them so they sort correctly. as at the moment I'm getting it sorting by the first number.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be really grateful.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that JavaScript's [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) "function doesn't do prices correctly", particularly when the `sort()` function has the capability for you to pass in a function that performs the comparison.

Comment: Please provide example data that is your input, desired output, and currently obtained output.

Comment: It just takes the first number so even though $3.60 is less that $10.30 it'll put the $10.30 first. The function sortByPrice literally just returns all the prices on the page. I presume they're stored in the options object but all get in there is Object Prototypes, lots of them. I can't find the prices anywhere. So it's where sortByPrice is putting the prices I'm really lost on.

Comment: Ok so this really isn't what I'd call a proper solution but it works. Since all my products are in MySQL and the site's built on PHP I simply took the price of the product in an array, ordered that array then ranked them using a date in the format Y-m-d H:i:s with the most expensive product having the latest date and going back from there. JS sorts that no problem. Not really a good JS solution but it works :) - I won't mark it as solved as I guess really it's not